# How to get the next line of the match usung regex in python

Tags: python, pandas, regex, numpy

```
Full name: Ajith Kumar
    First name :
       Ajith, aka actor
    Last name :
       Kumar 
    Age :
       55
```

So here, I want to write a code in python using regex to fetch the string "First name :".

When it matched the string then we should get next line I.e Ajith, aka actor.

Same for Last name as well.

I have written a code I.e `^.*\burst name[\s:]*(\b.*$)`
Bit it's not showing anything.

Comment: I think you have a typo `^.*\bFirst name[\s:]*(\b.*$)` https://regex101.com/r/ZpLHft/1 or write it like `^[^\S\n]*First name[^\S\n]*:[^\S\n]*\n[^\S\n]*(.*)` https://regex101.com/r/nlb0rE/1 if there has to be a colon and a single newline

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
your_string = '''
Full name: Ajith Kumar
    First name :
       Ajith, aka actor
    Last name :
       Kumar 
    Age :
       55'''
re.findall(r'First name :\n\s+([\w,\s]+)\n', your_string)
```

Output:

```
['Ajith, aka actor']
```

Similar for last name.